# How to use WM_Close in C#?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

Can anyone provide me an example of how to use WM_CLOSE to close a small application like Notepad?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Provided you already have a handle to send to.

```
...Some Class...
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

//I'd double check this constant, just in case
static uint WM_CLOSE = 0x10;

public void CloseWindow(IntPtr hWindow)
{
  SendMessage(hWindow, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
}
...Continue Class...
```

Getting a handle can be tricky.  Control descendant classes (WinForms, basically) have Handle's, and you can enumerate all top-level windows with [EnumWindows](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/EnumWindows.html) (which requires more advanced p/invoke, though only slightly).

Comment: I try this method, however, when send to a WPF application, it throw a System.Reflection.targetParameterCountException. Though it works fine with notepad.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you want to close notepad. the following code will do it:

```
    private void CloseNotepad(){
        string proc = "NOTEPAD";

        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
        var pc = from p in processes
                 where p.ProcessName.ToUpper().Contains(proc)
                 select p;
        foreach (var item in pc)
        {
            item.CloseMainWindow();
        }
    }
```

Considerations:

If the notepad has some unsaved text it will popup "Do you want to save....?" dialog or if the process has no UI it throws following exception

```
 'item.CloseMainWindow()' threw an exception of type 
 'System.InvalidOperationException' base {System.SystemException}: 
    {"No process is associated with this object."}
```

If you want to force close process immediately please replace

```
item.CloseMainWindow()
```

with

```
item.Kill();
```

If you want to go PInvoke way you can use handle from selected item.

```
item.Handle; //this will return IntPtr object containing handle of process.
```

Comment: need to read the question, @karthik wants to close a.n.other application

Comment: @Hamish I think adding *other* would have helped like, *other small application like notepad*

Comment: where do i need to give the name of applciation to close it ?

Comment: @karthik I've changed the whole answer to meet the **Requirement Specefication** :)

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot, where have u used the WM_close ?

Comment: It is just killing the applicaiton directly, right ? Thats why i want to use WM_close. Thanks.