# How to safely close Google Chrome programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, google-chrome

How can i safely close google chrome via C#? I can kill chrome process, but in this case Google Chrome will report appcrash on next run.

Comment: Get a handle to Chrome's windows and send `WM_CLOSE` to each of them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129204/how-to-use-wm-close-in-c

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055753/how-to-gracefully-terminate-a-process

Comment: I am just curious... by default google chrome or any other browser would alert me that an application is trying to close the browser? Thinking as a user I think this is a very annoying process. Most of the time I have so many tab´s opened and I just don´t want to close everything. As each tab has its own process, would not be better to close a specific tab instead of the whole browser?

Comment: @Guilherme I need to close browser, because I need to modify SQLite Chrome database(set my default search provider).

Comment: I did not know we could manipulate Chrome database. Now that you said it make sense that you close the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to determine the window handle(s) using the `Process` class and send a `WM_CLOSE` message to the window.

Answer (score 11):

You could use the little known [UI Automation API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx), like this:

```
static void CloseAllChromeBrowsers()
{
    foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome"))
    {
        if (process.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero) // some have no UI
            continue;

        AutomationElement element = AutomationElement.FromHandle(process.MainWindowHandle);
        if (element != null)
        {
            ((WindowPattern)element.GetCurrentPattern(WindowPattern.Pattern)).Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks great,but I .net 2.0 compatible solution

Comment: You should have stated *that* in the question.

Comment: Unfortunatly if you have multiple chrome windows open this will not close the first one.

Comment: Worked well for me!! Thanks Simon.  Namespaces required:
using System.Diagnostics,
using System.Windows.Automation

Comment: I had to reference UIAutomationClient and UIAutomationTypes.